# Asp.Net 5.0 MVC Multiple Project Image Upload

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to upload file in 3 projects, but the projects need to use together these files. How can I do it ?

Comment: By "Project" you mean a web appliacation? Are the projects hosted on the same server?

Comment: Create 4 instead of 3 one for image handling. The image handler project should provide feature (API) of upload and download image. You may call that directly or though you 3 projects. But you should provide more details. It may help to understand the problem statement.

Comment: @TheMixy Yes There was a Asp.Net Core MVC Web Project and they are in the same project.

Comment: One option is like @शेखर suggested, also you can simply create a shared folder on the server to which all 3 app pools save (and access) documents, or you can save the documents directly to a database to which all three app have access to. Saving to a shared folder on the server seems to me the simplest way (but not neccessarily the best)